# How to do a for loop in liquid with range

Tags: php, html, shopify, liquid

I am attempting to have a for loop in my template to loop through each letter of the alphabet, and if the first letter of the alphabet is found, print out that data.

I cannot find a way to do this, i know how to do this in PHP, but cannot get it to work in liquid.

```
{% for range('a','z') as $i %}   

    {% if first_letter == $i %}

        {% unless first_letter == current %}

            <li class="test"><h2 id='{{ first_letter }}'>{{ first_letter }}</h2> </li>

        {% endunless %}

        <ul><li class="test"> {{ product_vendor | link_to_vendor  }} </li>    </ul>

        {% assign current = first_letter %}

    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

The top two lines is what is not working here, i know the syntax is incorrect, but i cannot figure out how to get this to work.

Answer (score 5):

The syntax for ranges in liquid for loops is [here in the Shopify docs](http://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/tags/iteration-tags#for):

```
{% assign num = 4 %}
{% for i in (1..num) %}
  {{ i }} 
{% endfor %}

{% for i in (3..5) %}
  {{ i }} 
{% endfor %}
```

However, you can only use numbers in the range, not strings.

<s>Have you seen [this article](http://littlesnippets.ca/blogs/tutorials/15347169-alphabetical-vendor-categorization-with-liquid)? Maybe that approach would work in your situation.</s>

**Edit:** [Updated link for above article](http://shopify-tutorials.myshopify.com/blogs/tutorials/15347169-alphabetical-vendor-categorization-with-liquid).

Comment: That is the code i am using funny enough, but i just cannot get it to style into columns properly as i want a two column approach, similar to: http://www.selfridges.com/en/OnlineBrandDirectory but really having problems separating the columns

Comment: @DomGreensladeBSc Try using a [cycle](http://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/tags/iteration-tags#cycle).

Answer (score 0):

We are talking about liquid here, so you don't have many options. This will work fine, but make sure you complete alphabet.

```
{% assign letters = "a b c d e f g h i j" | split: ' ' %}
{% for letter in letters %}
    {% if letter == 'g' %}
         <!-- Letter {{ letter }} match! -->
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```